# Golang - reading user input from stdin after reading already

Tags: go

I would like to be able to read fully from stdin and then get input, also from stdin. I can read the input sent to my code but then I can't read user input. Is there any way around this? I'm doing this as part of a paging tool I am writing.

```
Read incoming

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        sb.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("%s\n", scanner.Text()))
    }


Reading user input

    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    text, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
```

Here is part of the code that reads from stdin then tries to read from input. When stdin is read first ReadString('\n') does not wait and results in a zero length string. If ReadString is read but the initial read from stdin is not made ReadString waits properly. I get EOF in the second call. I'll look into this and see what I can do.

```
var r = bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)

var contents string
var err error
contents, err = io.ReadAll(r)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

text, err := r.ReadString('\n')
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
fmt.Println(txt)
```

Comment: Please explain how you are running the program and providing both kinds of input.

Comment: My code first reads any input from stdin. I use cat to send text to the program. When I do that I can read the input from stdin but if I then try to read typed in input using reader.ReadString('\n') or fmt.Scanln() nothing is picked up. It seems that reading first from stdin prevents the later input from being obtained. If I do not first read from stdin the user input is read as expected.

Comment: Pleas edit your question to include the relevant info. For example, show what shell command(s) you are using. By the way, creating multiple buffered readers from the same source isn't a good idea, since they don't share the same buffer.

Comment: You still haven't shown how exactly you are providing the inputs to the program.

Comment: You're running your program like `cat file.txt | program` and then you're typing more input?

Comment: Yes, thank-you. I am. The issue is that once I read the standard input running ReadString('\n') does not wait for input. The value returned from ReadString is an empty string and the error returned is EOF. I've used stdin several times but I have never tried to read stdin then read additional input.

Answer (score 2):

> My code first reads any input from stdin. I use cat to send text to the program. When I do that I can read the input from stdin but if I then try to read typed in input using reader.ReadString('\n') or fmt.Scanln() nothing is picked up.

You're running your program like `cat file.txt | program` and then you're typing more input and trying to read that, too.

A program's stdin is normally inherited from the parent process. If you're running from an interactive shell, that's input from the terminal (ie. the keyboard).

`cat file.txt | program` redirects stdin to read from the output of `cat`. Stdin no longer points at the input from the terminal.

You'll have to reopen a stream to the terminal and write to that. You do this by reading from `/dev/tty`. `tty, err := os.Open("/dev/tty")`.

Comment: That makes perfect sense and using that works properly. Very much appreciate your insight.

I ended up using
 tty, err := os.Open("/dev/tty")
 var r = bufio.NewReader(tty)